# Export Fit Statistics and variance/covariance matrix to dta dataset

Tags: export, stata, dta

I'd like to export fit statistics (log likelihood, AIC, BIC) to a table in dta format.  I can display fit statistics after fitting the model (created using strsmix) easily enough using `estimates stats`, or `estat ic`, but I can't seem to find a way to write that to a proper .dta file.

I have the same problem with exporting the variance covariance matrix.  I can display it using `estat vce`, but I can't see to find a way to export it.

Comment: one thing you could do is use `mat2txt` or `putexcel` from scc with matrices and then load the text/excel file into Stata

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I was able to find a solution extracting the matrix without going through excel format, though I still need to figure out how to preserve labels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figure out a solution that works OK, but doesn't seem to preserve labels.

```
estat ic
matrix fit = r(S)
estat vce
matrix vce = r(V)
clear
svmat double fit, name(fit)
save fit.dta, replace
clear
svmat double vce, name(vce)
save vce.dta, replace
clear
```